# Preview Oh My Zsh completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I would like to preview what, if anything, would be completed using oh-my-zsh suggestions. In other words, a visual indicator that pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> will insert what I think it will.

- in different color (like zsh-autosuggestions shows it in grey)
- without changing current oh-my-zsh completion behavior (that's why I didn't just switch to zsh-autosuggestions completely)

How can I achieve this?